# Simple JavaScript Function that returns the parameter of greater value

Tags: javascript, function

I'm learning how to build functions and my task is to create a function declaration that will return the parameter of greater value. So far, I've only learned how to sums and products -- in other words, I don't know how to get JavaScript to "decide" which parameter is greater.

The extact task description is as follows: Build a function declaration called maxOf2 that takes in two numbers and returns the greater value. Be careful to think about the possibility of equality as well and return one of the numbers.

I've read about Math.max(), but as the course hasn't covered that, I'm not supposed to use it.

Here is what I have so far, which is not much:

```js
function maxOf2(a, b) {
  var a = 12;
  var b = 4;
  
  return ...;
 }
```

Comment: if (a > b) return ...

Answer (score 1):

Very basic example:

```
function maxOf(a, b){
    if(a > b){
        return a;
    } else {
        return b;
    }
}
```

You can use that `Math.max()` function like so:

```
Math.max(a, b);
```

And another example that uses [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
function maxOf(a, b){
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

Comment: And just keep in mind this will return `b` if the two numbers are equal as well

Comment: ` else { ` is superfluous. Just return b

Comment: @ChristopherMesser If they're equal it doesn't really seem to matter which one is returned.

Comment: No it doesn't, but the OP clearly does not have a strong grip on how to build a basic function so I wanted to clarify what would happen in the case of equal numbers.

Comment: I tried this exact same code block before posting here, but the Code School software returned an error message saying the function created does not return the greater value...

Comment: @drew.sparkman *Exact* same? If you produced code, why not include it? We won't bite!

Comment: Of course you could also check if they are even numbers first, and minimize the code a lot but I just posted an easily understandable answer to the specific question @drew.sparkman had.

Comment: @SvenTheSurfer I tried inserting a screenshot of the code from Code School, but I'm new here and don't have that capability yet.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer because there are only 3 answers:

```
const maxOf = (a,b) => (a > b ? a : b);
```

Comment: _I've read about Math.max(), but as the course hasn't covered that, I'm not supposed to use it._ I fell for the same...